# Не могу взять местоположение

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api, google-maps

Всем привет. Есть карта и на ней Геокардинация. Строка поиска, когда там вводишь какую-то местность, он отмечает это место маркером. Я беру координаты этого места, запускаю их в `alert();` - все работает, но в консоли он показывает массив. Так вот, как мне получить `lat` и `lot` из этого массива?

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
   var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
   geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: resultsMap,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
         });
         //Тут показывает координыта
         alert(results[0].geometry.location);
         //А тут показывет массив
         console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
      } else {
         alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
   });
}
```

Буду благодарен ребят всем, кто поможет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будьте внимательней `lat` это функция а функции необходимо вызвать.

```
console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
```

Comment: не так я уже пробов

Comment: я же не вижу какой там массив, попробуй так results[0].geometry.location[0].lot

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple?hl=ru вот отсюда брал

Comment: Смотрите ответ, обновил.

Comment: Точно Друг благодарю!Я даж не заметил что это функции внутри массива